# NodeJS - Sending SQL Results to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a script that will query a local database and send the results to a Google Spreadsheet. Where I am currently stuck and looking for help is how do I get the results of my query.

```
var myQuery = [];

function runQuery(query, callback) {

  client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    client.query(query, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      callback({ result: result });

      client.end(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    });
  });
}

runQuery('SELECT item_number FROM item WHERE item_number LIKE \'11-%\' LIMIT 10', function (resultsObject) {  
  myQuery = JSON.stringify(resultsObject.result.rows);
  console.log('Did stringify work?');
  console.log(myQuery);
});

console.log(myQuery);
```

My output:

```
Info: Start process (3:46:11 PM)
[]
Did stringify work?
[{"item_number":"11-0011"},{"item_number":"11-0012"},{"item_number":"11-1255"},{"item_number":"11-0052"},{"item_number":"11-0060"},{"item_number":"11-1256"},{"item_number":"11-1281"},{"item_number":"11-0659"},{"item_number":"11-0660"},{"item_number":"11-0054"}]
Info: End process (3:46:12 PM)
```

I think I understand what's happening, the scope of the variable myQuery is set and printed within the runQuery function just fine, but outside of that function it's not being actually set. How do I get around this?

Very new to JavaScript and NodeJS so I hope I'm using the correct terminology.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty myQuery has already been consoled before you actually put values into it. This issue is caused by Javascript's Asynchronous mechanism. If you want to do something with the result, you have to use a callback function. Just like what you did when you accessed result from runQuery.

Another way to do it is promise. You can return a promise in some function and use the promise to access result.

If you decide to use promise, here is the code:

```
function getresult(parameters) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        runQuery(parameter, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

Using this function, you passed resolve as callback to runQuery. You do want to add another err callback function to catch err in runQuery. In promise you use reject as err callback.

When you want to do something with the result:

```
getresult(parameters)
.then((result) => {put your code here. result variable is your result})
.catch((err) => {do whatever with err});
```

Comment: Here is a good instruction: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a scope issue. It is a timing issue. The query takes some time to execute. JavaScript is 'non-blocking' meaning it will start an asynchronous process (like doing a DB query - really virtually all I/O operations) and return the result later. In your code you are using a callback that is run once the data becomes available.

So, with that in mind, the way to think about your code is that you are doing things in this order:

1) declaring your function `runQuery` - this happens first since in JavaScript function declarations are moved to the top of the script they are in (a process called `hoisting`)
2) your variable myQuery is established and initialized (to an empty array)
3) your query is kicked off by a call to `runQuery`; this only starts the process
4) your `console.log(myQuery)` at the end of your script is run
5) some time later the query completes and your callback is called with the data where your other console.log() shows the returned data